# Splitting string into chunks by applying some rules

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to split `abc49.99ab55.5def89de7` into chunks to get result (or similar) below. **NOTE**: only `abc`, `ab`, `def` and `de` are allowed. the numbers can be float.

Ideally this:

```
Array
(
    [abc] => 49.99
    [ab] => 55.5
    [def] => 89
    [de] => 7
)
```

This is fine too:

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc49.99
    [1] => ab55.5
    [2] => def89
    [3] => de7
)
```

After seeing some examples, I've come up with examples below but unfortunately cannot enhance them to meet the needs as defined above. Would you please help in this matter?

**1**

```
preg_match('/(?<fo>abc|ab)?(?<fn>\d*\.?\d*)(?<so>def|de)?(?<sn>\d*\.?\d*)?/', 'abc49.99ab55.5def89de7', $matches);

Array
(
    [0] => abc49.99
    [fo] => abc
    [1] => abc
    [fn] => 49.99
    [2] => 49.99
    [so] => 
    [3] => 
    [sn] => 
    [4] => 
)
```

**2**

```
preg_match_all('~^(.*?)(\d+)~m', 'abc49.99ab55.5def89de7', $matches);

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc49
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 49
        )

)
```

Comment: `$str = "abc49.99ab55.5def89de7";
  print_r(preg_split("/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])/i", $str));`

Comment: @Rizier123 - Excellent. That does exactly what I want so please add your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from OP's [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472749/splitting-string-into-chunks-by-applying-some-rules?noredirect=1#comment50911276_31472749). This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $str = "abc49.99ab55.5def89de7";
    $arr = preg_split("/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])/i", $str);
    print_r($arr);

?>
```

regex explanation:

```
/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z])/i
```

- (**?<=**[0-9]) [**Positive Lookbehind**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) - Assert that the regex below can be matched

  - [0-9] match a single character present in the list below

    - 0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
- (**?=**[a-z]) [**Positive Lookahead**](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php) - Assert that the regex below can be matched

  - [a-z] match a single character present in the list below

    - a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case insensitive)

[flags](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

- **i** modifier: insensitive. Case insensitive match (ignores case of [a-zA-Z])